# How can I access an array's values inside a xhr object?

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I created an xhr request which gives back an object with an array of names which I want to write to the document. here is the object I receive from the request:

```
{description: "Names for employee feed", employees: Array(8)}

description: "Names for employee feed"

    employees: Array(8)
    0: {id: 1, first_name: "Allef", last_name: "Vinicius"}
    1: {id: 2, first_name: "Brook", last_name: "Cagle"}
    2: {id: 3, first_name: "Fayard", last_name: "Nicolas"}
    3: {id: 4, first_name: "Hasana", last_name: "Ayubu"}
    4: {id: 5, first_name: "Jake", last_name: "Young"}
    5: {id: 6, first_name: "Michelangelo", last_name: "Buonarroti"}
    6:
    id: 7
    first_name: "Moiraine"
    last_name: "Damodred"
    __proto__: Object
    7: {id: 8, first_name: "Rand", last_name: "Al'Thor"}
    length: 8
```

I'm can write the "description" to the document but I am having trouble accessing the names in the array.

```
const output = document.querySelector('.output');

let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhr.open('GET', 'https://techi.envivent.com/names.json', true);

xhr.onload = function(){
  if (this.status === 200) {

    let response = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
    console.log(response);

    output.innerHTML = `<h3>${response.description}<h3>
                        <p>${response.employee[0][1]}</p>
    `;
  }
}

xhr.send();
```

Comment: `response.employees[0].first_name`

Comment: thanks, one more question, say I have another xhr request that pulls in the descriptions from another file, how can I "group" these requests together?

Comment: You'll need to use callbacks or promises to coordinate them, since XHR is asynchronous.